# Is it possible to link a Google+ page to multiple web properties with rel="publisher" ?

Tags: google-plus, rich-snippets

I want to have the Google+ page of my startup linked to 2 domains: `blog.eatfab.com` and `www.eatfab.com` for the obvious reasons that they're both eatfab's properties. I wonder if that is possible. I'm able to link only one.

The problem is that when I try to see on google rich snippets tool who the publisher of `www.eatfab.com` is (when `blog.eatfab.com` appears as a linked url on the Google+ page), I get the error:

```
This is not a verified publisher markup.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you place the link to `eatfab.com` on your Google+ page, and have `<a href="https://plus.google.com/[yourpageID]" rel="publisher">Find us on Google+</a>` on both `www.eatfab.com` and `blog.eatfab.com` they should both be linked to your one Google+ page.

Comment: I did that, but google seems to consider only the url that is on the G+ page as a linked property. `Rich Snippets Tool` gives the error in the question body on this case: `This is not a verified publisher markup.`